# Different widgets (views) for different screen orientations?

Tags: android, android-widget, screen-orientation

I'm quite new developing for Android so I have a very basic question.

Basically, I have two screen layouts, one for portrait and another for landscape orientation. I use the folders res/layout and res/layout-land. Both orientations are drawn fine, but I have different widgets (buttons) for each orientation, btnPortrait and btnLandscape.

The problem arises when I try to call onSetClickListener(). Because when the device is oriented in portrait the framework can't locate the btnLandscape and viceversa, I handle the orientation changes manually using onConfigurationChange(). It doesn't seem to work either.

My code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnPortrait = (Button) findViewById(R.id.portraitButton);
    tvPortrait = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.portraitText);
    btnLandscape = (Button) findViewById(R.id.landscapeButton);
    tvLandscape = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.landscapeText);
}
```

And the onConfigurationChange():

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        btnPortrait.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Portrait",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    else {
        btnLandscape.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

None of the Toasts work.
Does somebody know what could be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have different buttons for each? Just give them the same ID and the Activity will look them up accordingly

Comment: They aren't aimed to the same function, in other words, they are two completely different buttons. I simplified the code with the Toast to not enter in the business model, which isn't related to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't name them differently; the widgets for the same function should share the same ID whether it's in portrait or landscape.

If it's a widget that only exists or functions differently in landscape, just check if it's null after findViewById(), and if that returns null, you know you're not in a configuration with a layout that includes that button.

Comment: You are correct, it returns null no matter where I try to initialize the button. Do you imagine a way to assign widgets that are in the landscape layout but not in the portrait layout? Thanks.

Comment: As I said, just try to resolve the button. If it's not null, then you know you're in the landscape layout.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that your button Id in layout-land is same Id in default layout

Update1 :

ok add not null check before using the widget like this

```
if( btnPortrait !=null ) { 
// do what you want 
}
```

Comment: As I said in my comment, they are not the same button. One it should appear in the portrait mode, and the other one in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure by what you mean in the comments by "they're not the same button" but a way of doing what you want with two different resource ids would be as follows...

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    Button myButton = null;
    TextView myTextView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.portraitButton);
        if (myButton == null)
            myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.landscapeButton);
        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.portraitText);
        if (myTextView == null)
            myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.landscapeText);
    }

    // The following method is your OnClickListener
    public void sayHello(View v) {
        switch (v.getId) {
            case R.id.portraitButton :
                // Do something for portrait
                break;
            case R.id.landscapeButton :
                // Do something for landscape
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

In your layout files you would then assign the `OnClickListener` using `android:onClick` as follows...

For portrait...

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/portraitButton"
    ...
    android:onClick="sayHello" >
</Button>
```

For landscape...

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/landscapeButton"
    ...
    android:onClick="sayHello" >
</Button>
```

In this way, the `OnClickListener` is set by the inflation process when `setContentView(...)` is called. It then simply comes down to it determining the resource id to decide what action needs to be taken.